# What is 'anyPropertyKey' in Angular filter definition?

Tags: angularjs

**Angular JS**

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator : anyPropertyKey}}
```

I am unable to understand the last argument i.e., anyPropertyKey. Can anybody please explain me with a **simple example**

```
<div ng-init="ar=[{n:'ram1', m:1}, {n:'mah', m:1}, {n:'vij', m:3}]">
    <div ng-repeat='x in ar | filter: "1": false: propertyName'>{{x}}</div>
</div>
```

this is what I tried so far. In the above code what I should write instead of propertyName.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `anyPropertyKey` is related to the expression of the filter. The relevant part of the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/filter/filter) is:

> A special property name ($ by default) can be used (e.g. as in {$:
>   "text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its
>   nested object properties. That's equivalent to the simple substring
>   match with a string as described above. The special property name can
>   be overwritten, using the anyPropertyKey parameter.

So the first thing here is that this expression:

```
<div ng-repeat='x in ar | filter: "1": false'>{{x}}</div>
```

is equivalent to this expression:

```
<div ng-repeat='x in ar | filter: {$:1}: false'>{{x}}</div>
```

So instead of a simple substring match, an object is used with a special key (`$` by default) to match any property of the object with the value `1`.

The `anyPropertyKey` parameter can be used to overwrite the default `$` property like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='x in ar | filter: {"@":1}: false: "@"'>{{x}}</div>
```

In this last example we use the `@` symbol to match any property name, freeing up the `$` for other purposes.

The following snippet shows the same output for all three expressions:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">
<div ng-init="ar=[{n:'ram1', m:1}, {n:'mah', m:1}, {n:'vij', m:3}]">
  <div ng-repeat='x in ar | filter: "1": false'>{{x}}</div>
  <hr />
  <div ng-repeat='x in ar | filter: {$:1}: false'>{{x}}</div>
  <hr />      
  <div ng-repeat='x in ar | filter: {"@":1}: false: "@"'>{{x}}</div>
  <hr />
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I want to get the object which contain value 1 in property n. How can I get?

Comment: You unintentionally also answered a different question I had about the filter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is already answered, in my case, I need to apply the filter in the controller. Following is the snippet for the same, if it helps someone.

```
In HTML 
<input placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchValue" ng-blur="filterCompleteData(searchValue, completeData)" class="input-sm-modified" type="search" />
```

In controller

```
$scope.filterCompleteData = function(searchValue, completeData){
$filter('filter')(completeData, {'$':searchValue})
}
```

By using `'$'` in place of object property name you can input text( in `searchValue` ) for any of the properties of the object, it will filter out that.

Answer (score 0):

`comparator` can be **true**, **false**, or a **function**:

- when `true`: it returns the match only if the value is **exactly**
  the same as in your object/array *(only "1", in your case)*
- when `false`: it returns the match if the value **contains** the
  value *(all lines that contains "1")*
- with a `function`: **whatever** you want that define how you match
  the value

By default, it is false, so if you just use `<div ng-repeat='x in ar | filter: "1">{{x}}</div>` it is the same as `filter: "1": false`.

---

If you want to look at a specific attribute in your object, use `ng-repeat='x in ar | filter: {n:"1"}`. Here you only search `"1"` in the `n` attribute of your object.

Comment: I didn't ask about `comparator`