# In angularjs's ng-model how parameters are added?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angular.js , and I understand with ng-model we attach the value (that we get from any input) to the controller's `$scope` object. But recently I am going through it's filters and I do not understand the example given in the angularjs's official site [filters in angular js](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) ,What I don't understand is

```
<label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label><br>
<label>Name only <input ng-model="search.name"></label><br>
<label>Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"></label><br>
<label>Equality <input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict"></label><br>
<table id="searchObjResults">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
        <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
        <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
```

in the above code how do we add the parameters to the ng-model and how are they being accessed ? because the ng-init has "friends" , how theses two are being related to perform the filter or search ?
I am just trying to understand how providing search.name or search.phone we are able to access friends.name and friends.phone respectively

Comment: do you want access avariable declared using nginit

Comment: `ng-model` is not a function, it does not have parameters. you can pass parameters to `filter` because it is a method on the `angular` object.

Comment: I am just trying to understand how providing search.name or search.phone we are able to access friends.name and friends.phone respectively .

Comment: Hi daniel_L ,
     This code was provided in the angularjs's official website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`friends` is object array. Each sub object of `friends` has `name` and `phone` properties. This object array is filled by ng-init as you said.

Also you have `search` object (model) in your scope. It has `name` and `phone` properties, too.

`friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict` is the standard usage for filter directive. It means that; filter "friends" using "search".

When you filter `friends` (object array) using `search` object AngularJS basically iterates over  `friends` and collects records which returns true for both `friendObj.name == search.name` and `friendObj.phone == search.phone` (In strict mode). If you set last (strict) parameter to false, it checks for substrings.

Comment: So you mean whenever the parameters of the object array and the search object have the exact name (name and phone) it will do a comparison, Kindly excuse me if i am wrong, I am trying to understand it well. Suppose if we give some different parameter (like search.age) then it won't show anything

Comment: Yes, you are right. If your search model has any extra property, filtered results will be empty. _(If you do not change comparator.)_ You can use **comparators** if you want to apply some other filter mechanisms like `"filter records with age > 18"` or `"filter records from 2016 May to 2017 May"`.

Comment: No, "anyPropertyKey" is completely different thing. It is like "wildcard". Sometimes you may need a filter mechanism which checks for "every" properties in object. For example, your object list may have different types of objects with different properties. One object type have "City" property, other one has "State" property. If you want to search through all these parameters, you can use anyPropertyKey. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605558/what-is-anypropertykey-in-angular-filter-definition) for further information.

Comment: Thanks Eker still this is little unclear to me.. I will study more on this and come back to you for any doubt

Comment: Actually, official example of AngularJS is very clear. At the top right of code section you can see "Edit in Plunker" button. You can click it and try these cases;

- Adding extra properties to search model
- Changing comperator ( ex: searching for greater values. )
- Try $ usage (anyPropertyKey). (Already visited on official example)
- EXPERT: Multidimensional object filtering

If you encounter any problem, share with us and we can solve it together.